# Practicing Vedas during evening time

Tags: vedas, rituals, practice, vedic-chanting

I have learnt Sri Rudram from a guru. Now I would like to keep on practising, learning and improving myself on it. Due to my job, etc. sometimes it may not be possible to learn early in the morning. So I am thinking of practising it during the evening.

My question is, are there any restrictions according to our shastras on practising during the evening? I got this doubt because I would have eaten breakfast and lunch, so I was thinking whether it is right to practise during the evening. Any guidance from people would be very helpful.

Comment: Here are some guidance https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31465/12304 and you can visit https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b069.htm for more details..

Comment: i've heard that it's not ok to chant during dark (after sunset). also, we must be ritually clean (shoucha) while chanting. so ideal time would be after morning bath, before breakfast. but if u take bath in evening (after lunch, before sunset), then i think it's ok.